# How set up raspberry pi to connect to from internet?

Tags: networking, ssh, home-networking, raspberry-pi

I simply want to be able to connect my RaspberryPI for example from work office. RaspberryPI is on my home network connected to router. I dont have public IP Address. I was thinking about hamachi, but I dont want to install software on computer at work, I just want to connect with PUTTY over SSH. List some options - preferable free of charge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you should set the SSH to pubkey only because the default username/password is not good then [this appp](https://ngrok.com/) can expose the SSH to the outside world for free:

```
ngrok tcp 22
```

Comment: okay, I ran it. Now, how to connect to it from internet?

Comment: @Julius if you run the program then it'll tell you an url but if you register then you just login then go to Status then the URL column.

Comment: Okay, it works. Do you also have the delay on terminal when connected over ngrok? It is not smooth as it should be. It is annoying.

Comment: @Julius well you could try to set the region with "-region=REGION" to a region closer to you. us for USA, eu for EU, ap for ASIA, and au for AUSTRALIA. For example "./ngrok tcp -region=eu 22" for the eu region.